# Adding User Testimonials

Tags: feature-request

As someone that has greatly benefited from using SO, I'd love to see a feature for user testimonials where the user can speak to any particular success that the site has enabled them to acheive.  **Question: Are there any plans to add user testimonials?**

Answer (score 4):

They are sometimes [added to the blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/09/i-heart-stack-overflow/), you can always email team@stackoverflow.com and tell them your story.

Comment: That is a good point, not sure what business value it would add to the site other than "hey our users like us."

Answer (score 1):

If you mean adding them to SO pages in some way, then I doubt it.

- There's no need to tell people how awesome something is if it really is awesome -- it's self-evident.
- Testimonials are usually used when the barrier to entry of something is moderate to high (which is not the case here).
- When it comes to what appears on pages, the trilogy sites are pretty focused on answering questions, not on the consequences (good or bad) of those questions.

All that being said, I think you have an interesting idea, but I don't think there's any need to put it on SO pages. As mentioned, e-mailing the SO team for them to share in their blog, or elsewhere, is probably the most appropriate -- they are the ones who deserve the praise anyway!

Answer (score 1):

How awesome is a service if customers are begging you to add a customer testimonial page?

I like the idea - I think it may be especially valuable now that they are [looking for funding](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/items/2010/02/14.html).  However, they may not be interested in publishing them on the site itself, so sending your testimonial to team@stackoverflow.com is still your best bet.